# How to access and change the NSAttributedString title of a custom barButtonItem composed by UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I made a custom barButtonItem in my toolbar. I want to change the string of the NSAttributedString when the barButtonItem has been tapped. But as the apple document said the performance of the function is charged by the customView, not the barButtonItem any more, how can I access and do some change to the details of it according to events?

```
    let button1 = UIButton(type: .System)
    button1.sizeToFit()
    let attributes1 = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)]
    let attributedString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello", attributes: attributes1)
    button1.setAttributedTitle(attributedString1, forState: .Normal)
    button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActionViewController.switchAccounts), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    let account = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button1)

    setToolbarItems([account], animated: true)
```

I'm a new swifter. OC can also be read by me.
Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use your custom button action method like this

```
func switchAccounts(sender : UIButton)  {
    let attributes1 = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)]
    let attributedString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "world!", attributes: attributes1)

    sender.setAttributedTitle(attributedString1, forState: .Normal)
    sender.sizeToFit()
}
```

and

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActionViewController.switchAccounts(_:))
```

instead of

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActionViewController.switchAccounts)
```

Comment: Thank you. It's my solution at last.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone found that stackoverflow can be used as a little yellow duck? lol

```
for item in toolbarItems! where item.tag == 1000 {
        let attributes1 = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)]
        let attributedString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "world!", attributes: attributes1)

        let button = item.customView as! UIButton
        button.setAttributedTitle(attributedString1, forState: .Normal)
        button.sizeToFit()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**change target code as below.**

```
button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ActionViewController.switchAccounts(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Make **switchAccounts()** like below.

```
func switchAccounts(sender:UIButton){
    sender.selected = !sender.selected
    let attributes1 = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor(), NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(13)]
    let attributedString1 = NSAttributedString(string: "Hello click", attributes: attributes1)
    sender.setAttributedTitle(attributedString1, forState: .Selected)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's my solution at last.